# how to hide this button during convert of html page to pdf using iText in Spring Boot and Thymleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, itext, thymeleaf, html-to-pdf

I am facing problem during pdf generation when I am converting html page into pdf that time button is also showing, but requirement is button should not be show but button should be on same page and after click PDF should be generate. I am using iText for Pdf generation. I am using Thymeleaf and Spring Boot.

[image: this is them pdf view after generation of pdf]
I have used this code for pdf generation.

```
@RequestMapping("download-pdf/{refno}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getPDF(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@PathVariable("refno") Long refno) throws IOException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

    complaintDto = complaintRepo.findById(refno).orElse(null);
    complaintPdfBean = pdfService.getComplaintInfo(complaintDto);

    WebContext context = new WebContext(request, response, servletContext);
    context.setVariable("complaintPdfBean", complaintPdfBean);
    String grievanceHtml = templateEngine.process("complant-privew", context);

    ByteArrayOutputStream target = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
    converterProperties.setBaseUri("http://localhost:8080");
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(grievanceHtml, target, converterProperties);
    byte[] bytes = target.toByteArray();

    return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=grievance.pdf")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF).body(bytes);

}
```

[image: this is the html page view where is the button on same html page]

I am using this maven dependency in pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- pdf dependency -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your button with a `<th:block>` and an `th:unless` statement:

```
<th:block th:unless="${isPdfExport}">
 ...
</th:block>
```

Set the `isPdfExport` context variable to `true` just before the PDF generation.

Comment: Hi Wim I am not getting this point where your are saying to set isPdfExport context variable true. can you elaborate me. I have given here my Controller code of PDF generation.

Comment: Add this in your controller: `context.setVariable("isPdfExport", true);`